# Javascript - Nest select dropdown inside text

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to have a container such as:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Option 1: {{ dropDown1}} Option 2: {{ dropDown2 }}</h2>
        //submit button
    </div>
</div>
```

Where I have two 'select' dropdowns inside my single line of text. I can have it working in the following manner for functionality:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">Select your configuration options:</h2>
        <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options" data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
        <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options2" data-ng-model="selectedOption"></select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using two individual dropdown boxes (I am using angular), but these will show up below my text and not achieve the desired result I want. Any idea how I can nest these dropdowns in between text?

Answer (score 1):

Your first select isn't closed.

To get them on the same line, give them css: 'display: inline-block' or 'float: left'. (There are more ways to do this using css, you should really learn css if you want to work with html).

Answer (score 0):

To have the `<select>` elements flow inside the `<h2>` header, use `<span>` elements to contain the text:

```html
<h2 style="text-align:center;">
    <span>Option 1:</span>
    <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options"
            data-ng-model="selectedOption">      
    </select>
    <span>Option 2: </span>
    <select data-ng-options="o.name for o in options"
            data-ng-model="selectedOption">      
    </select>
</h2>
```